# Spring+JPA @Transactional not committing 

Tags: spring

I understand the similar question have been asked before here, but I couldn't find the solution to my problem. Basically, I am trying to use JPA through Hibernate in Spring, but the data is **not** being persisted for some reason.Turning on debug on spring transaction reveals nothing - EntityManager open and closed, but nothing shows up as far as transaction manager concerns ... I am sure I miss something big, any help is appreciated! see the following for more details.

TIA

Oliver

The basic layout is as follows: class `FooDaoJPA`’s save function calls out `entityManager.persist(object)` to persist the object.

class `FooServiceImpl` implements the service interface by:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = DataAccessException.class,
                    readOnly = false, timeout = 30,
                    propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS,
                    isolation = Isolation.DEFAULT)
 public void saveFoo(Foo foo) throws DataAccessException {
        fooDao.save(foo);
}
```

Noted that `fooDao` is injected by Spring IoC

Finally controller is injected a `FooService` and call `saveFoo()` to persist data.

JPA configuration

```
<!-- JPA Entity Manager Factory -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
          p:dataSource-ref="feDataSource"/>

<!-- Transaction Config -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
          p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"                        
transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

Comment: remove rollbackFor = DataAccessException.class  and surround dao call with try catch for debug purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the `mode="aspectj"` in your configuration. It requires additional configuration and usually you shouldn't use it unless you understand what does it mean and why do you need it. See [10.5.6 Using @Transactional](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations).

Comment: Though the answer doesn't directly address the problem, but I think the "aspectj" and its related configuration (doing load time weaving) is the culprit of problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that looks like a potential issue is your setting for *propagation*. Here is documentation showing the values you can specify:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html

Note that you've specified SUPPORTS which "Support a current transaction, execute non-transactionally if none exists". You probably want REQUIRED, which is the default, and will either use an existing transaction or create one if one does not currently exist.

Comment: First, thx for the reply. And though what you suggested make sense, but I tried with propagation required, it doesn't seem make a difference. Also, the original setting I took from Apress book "Spring Persistence with JPA" - but there are quite a number of typo/inconsistencies in that book, I wouldn't bet on it either.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

Using JPA with Spring MVC - all of my tests and code ran fine without error - symptom was that commits would simply not save to the database no matter what I tried.

I had to add 
to my applicationContext.xml and cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar aopalliance-1.0.jar

Definitely the fix in my case. Without annotation-driven Spring will not scan for the @Transactional annotation